# Problems of emulating a PS3 game with rpcs3

Tags: ps3, emulation

The emulator says LLE modules are needed to boot a game.
But I do not know what kind of LLE is needed.
So I just loaded the LLE inside the game folder `PS3_GAME\USRDIR\prx`.
When I booted the game, a lot of `unknown module` and `opengl failed` errors appeared in the log console.

---

Emulator: rpcs3 (latest build)
PS3 game: Mobile Suit Gundam Extreme Vs. Full Boost
OS : Windows 7 x64

---

Please help me.
I am completely new with PS3 stuffs.
If I need to provide log files or other details,
please comment.

Comment: You might want to look into the offical forums for rpcs3: http://www.emunewz.net/forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=163

Comment: I'm curious how this counts as unreleased or illegal; by my recollection, we help with emulation.

Comment: Both rpcs3 and game are not unreleased or illegal. It is just a different way to play games like using PPSSPP/mame.